# Visual Studio 2010 prevent JScript debugging on certain files

Tags: javascript, jquery, visual-studio-2010, debugging

Is it possible to prevent the Javascript debugger from stepping into certain files?

I specifically don't want it to break when an exception is thrown in the Jquery JavaScript file:

[image]

The same goes for other 3rd party minified files...every time there is a run time error it shows the notification and opens up the file. Breaking execution and opening the minified file  doesn't help me find the cause of the error.

Answer (score 2):

Something is causing the error, and you probably shouldn't just ignore it.

I'd recommend switching to the debug (unminified) script and figured out what exactly the error is.

Once you have the error, if you can't figure it out, post it on stackoverflow and I'm sure someone will be able to help you out more.

Try running your custom scripts through jslint to see if there are any obvious problems. http://www.jslint.com

Edit: Based on your error, I'd say you are trying to do something with a null value, make sure you check for nulls in your code when it's a possibility that something could be null. You can assign default values like this:

```
variable = (typeof variable === undefined) ? defaultValueIfNull : variable;
```

or use the same check with if statements

```
if (typeof variable !== undefined)
{
    //do stuff
}
```

And because it's jquery and it says object expected, I'd say you may have a selector that doesn't return any matches, but it could be other things, that's just a guess.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I dont plan to just ignore the error...I realise its a error caused by an undefined variable. I just want to find a way to stop VS from breaking into the jquery code. Im basically looking for a way to say I trust the minified jQuery code so please don't step into it - my code is the problem!

Comment: None that I know of, though I do sympathize with you on that, if you don't have proper breakpoints set up and end up inside of the jquery code it can be annoying, I think attaching the debugger is pretty much all or nothing. Perhaps add some try, catches in your functions to prevent the errors from bubbling up to the jquery?

Comment: also, step over functions that call jquery, instead of step into and you should be able to see where the error is. I use firebug for debugging usually. Or the Visual Studio debugger from time to time.